# Vuex - How to make multilevel array reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

How to make multilevel array reactive?

I have something like this.

```
state.scenes[state.sceneIndex].contents[payload.contentIndex]
```

whereas Scene and Content have their own components. I was able to update the data in Vuex however, the changes are not reflecting in the UI. I already tried using

```
Vue.set(state.scenes[state.sceneIndex].contents, payload.contentIndex, payload.value)
```

but didn't work.

Will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

It was the `...MapState` that causes this issue.

I just created another computed that returns the value from mapState.

```
computed: {
   ...mapState('SomeModule', ['SomeState']),
   someName() {
     return this.someState
   }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping an existing computed property in another computed property is unlikely to be fixing anything. There isn't sufficient information in the question to identify what is really going on here but this looks a lot like *programming by coincidence*.

Comment: Can you provide a better idea or better fix? if not, why bother commenting in here?

Comment: I can't provide a better answer as there isn't sufficient information provided in the question to establish what the true problem is. However, it seems very unlikely from the information that has been provided that this answer is actually correct. It seems much more likely that you have misunderstood or misinterpreted something and that it either doesn't fix the problem at all or only fixes it indirectly. You could clarify the situation by including an explanation in your answer of why it fixes the problem.